# How to find documents using a field of an embedded document that is inside an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the Data/Schema for my student records:

```js
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("579ed0ba7d509178a97fae8f"),
    "fullName" : "ABC",
    "enroll" : "AB1234",
    "profile" : {
        "isCompleted" : true,
        "verification" : [ 
            {
                "pro" : true,
                "verifiedBy" : "ProAct",
                "verifiedOn" : ISODate("2016-09-12T07:36:53.680Z")
            }, 
           
        ],
        "isChecked" : false,
        "fullName" : "ABC",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "emergencyContactPerson" : {
            "name" : "Father",
            "mobile" : "9412345678",
            "email" : "example@gmail.com",
        },
    },
    "contact" : {
        "emailID" : {
            "isVerified" : true,
            "isChecked" : false,
            "verificationTokenExpiresIn" : ISODate("2016-08-01T05:35:00.218Z"),
            "verifiedOn" : ISODate("2016-08-01T04:35:10.992Z")
        },
        "mobileID" : {
            "isVerified" : true,
            "isChecked" : false,
            "verificationTokenExpiresIn" : ISODate("2016-08-01T04:42:45.206Z"),
            "verifiedOn" : ISODate("2016-08-01T04:33:36.692Z")
        }
    },
    "services" : [ 
        {
            "applied" : true,
            "appliedOn" : ISODate("2016-09-17T03:01:49.829Z"),
            "status" : "Created",
            "mac" : "70-77-88-00-AA-BB",
            "createdBy" : "Example"
        },
    ]
}
```

How can I build query, to get student info with the help of mac address 70-77-88-00-AA-BB. i only know mac address value?

i am new here please help me out

Comment: You are trying to query on an embedded array field; see the MongoDB Manual topic on [Query an Array of Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

Answer (score 0):

Query

- `services.mac` is an array of all the mac addresses members of services
- in querying(not in aggregation `$eq`) an array is equal with a value if it contains that value, so the above will work
- the bellow query returns all the students, that have that mac adrress on the services array
- if you want to make it fast you can also create an index on "services.mac"

*read mongodb documentation its very good and with examples

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nwH83kE7zAt)

```js
db.collection.find({
  "services.mac": "70-77-88-00-AA-BB"
})
```